# Redirect page after form submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<body onload="document.action.submit()">
<form name="action" method="post" action="https://en.educaplay.com/en/registrar.php" >
<input type="hidden" name="action" value='loginTicket'>

    <input name="ticket" type="text" id="ticket" value="<%= session[:educa_key] %>">
    <input type="submit" name="entrar" id="entrar2" value="Sign in" class="btn">
</form>
```

Now, I want to redirect the submitter to any page of my choice after the form data has been submitted, but the action resides on another website where I cannot edit. Is it possible to redirect the user to any page after he has submitted the data to that site? I have checked a number of suggestions but not sucess at this point. thanks in advance

Comment: You have your form set to submit the data right as the page loads? Why not just use JavaScript AJAX/XHR to send the data and then use `window.location.href="";` to redirect the window? (Ignoring any "Disable JavaScript" responses.)

Comment: Yes, i would like to submit asap as im trying to make it automatically for the user...the user doent even know about the login page its like just click in the link,realize the login without the user knowing it and redirect to page of my choice. I am new at development so im not sure how to use ajax

Comment: Okay, then take a look at XHTTP Requests via JavaScript. If you're using PHP, scratch that. Take a look at jQuery AJAX.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put link in last comment. Visit https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp to learn about AJAX and its capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, there will be an automatic browser redirection to the URL you specified in the `action` attribute of your form. Here is a minimal example:

```html
<form action="http://stackoverflow.com">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now, if you want to code a form properly, you should follow the **Post/Redirect/Get** pattern. Ajax is a viable solution for what you want to do:

```
(function () {
  // Dummy submit handler
  function handler() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = "action.php",
        params = "foo=Foo&bar=Bar";

    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
      }
    }

    xhr.send(params);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Andy deleted his message. ;) By the way, I'm modifying my answer to make it clearer...

Comment: Yeah, deleted mine, too. Sounded too much like a... um... "doodle." :)

Comment: @TyQ. We're talking to phantoms... xD

Comment: xD Also, good job. Like the way you set up your answer. Except in the JavaScript section, why do you have `(function(){})();` I know it's to be immediately invoked as JSLint likes to put it, but...?

Comment: I like IIFEs. In ES5, there are useful to wait for the DOM. It is a great replacement for the well-known `$(document).ready(function () {});` in jQuery. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your `registar.php` file, add `header('Location: https://www.example.com/example.html');`

This isn't necessarily JavaScript, but it's probably the most efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have to wait for the answer, you can use javascript (jquery if you want and can) for this:

```
$("#entrar2").click(function(){
    $(location).href(link);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submission will cancel the redirect.

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return redirect()">  
   <input type="submit" class="button4" name="order" id="order" value="Place Order" >
</form>

<script>
    function redirect() {
        window.location.replace("login.php");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("formId").onsubmit=function() {
   window.location.replace("https://jsfiddle.net/");
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send your data to other website using curl before form submitted.Where you can process your data or store it . And after successful response from other page you can redirect user to any page